# How can I surpass "Press any key to continue ..." in python?

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

In my project I am starting a `.bat` file from a python script. Just like this:

```
os.system("testfile.bat")
```

When this `` `testfile.bat `` is finished it ends with the prompt `Press any key to continue ...`. I would like my python script to surpass this prompt and somehow simulate the keypress.

How can I achieve that? I already implemented this functionality by using a subprocess but as it turned out a subprocess is not suited for the context of my project (has something to do with printing to the console). Any ideas?

Comment: Does 'testfile.bat' have a `pause` at the end?

Comment: The `pause` gives the "Press any key to continue ..." prompt. Just remove the `pause` from the batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html) module is *always* suited and superior to `os.system`.

Just do

```
sp = subprocess.Popen("testfile.bat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
sp.stdin.write("\r\n") # send the CR/LF for pause
sp.stdin.close() # close so that it will proceed
```

and you should be done.

Comment: That's assuming that `testfile.bat` doesn't have any other programs that read standard input. OP doesn't say that `testfile.bat` is non-interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Add `>nul` to the end of the pause commend (In the batch file.) it will not print "Press any key to continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "pause" at the end of your Bat file just remove it, it will continue executing the rest of python script after the subprocess is done.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("testfile.bat", shell=False, \
                          cwd=path_to_exe)

p.wait()
```